# String not readable after newline from .env in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I added one key variable in .env file in nodeJS application as below.

```
KEY="---Key---
..............
..............
"
```

When i try to get this variable from .env it got only "---Key---".
I don't know why.

Comment: Please read the documentation: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#rules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot put your env variable on multiple lines.
Just write it on one line, using double quotes, and use `\n` in between lines.
You can see it here: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#rules

Comment: It looks like as of version 15.0.0, you can indeed put your environment variable on multiple lines: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#:~:text=If%20you%20need%20multiline%20variables%2C%20for%20example%20private%20keys%2C%20those%20are%20now%20supported%20(%3E%3D%20v15.0.0)%20with%20line%20breaks%3A

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple line string on env variable, you need to use `\n` wherever new line requires. Please see the example below.

## index.js

```
require('dotenv').config();                                                                                                               
console.log(process.env.TEST);
```

## .env

```
TEST="Hi! how are you? \n I am fine."
```

## out put

```
Hi! how are you? 
I am fine.
```